# Send an ARP probe message

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have an IP address and I want to know if it's available or not. After googling, I know that a possible solution is to create an ARP probe message and then send it to that address. To complete that task, DatagramSocket will be used. Can you tell me how to create such message (I don't know very much about networking) and, if possible, give me a small example.

Thank you.

Comment: People are more likely to help if you elaborate on what you've tried, or what you don't understand.  Questions just asking for the code are not always well received.

Comment: In fact, I want to implement a DHCP-like using actionscript, this is one part of my student-project, I'm now seeking for possible solutions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this using a JSP service to ping multiple servers then return a result in XML which my flex app reads and renders server status's. You could do it without a service middle layer, just using actionscript, but it will be a bit longer as you have to wait for the 404 error message to return from each page.

Method 1:
Use JSP (or most any other language) to create a service that polls the IP's (I poll for IP's and ports on those IP's) you want and return XML that Flash reads and renders.

Method 2:
Use multiple HTTPService call's inside of flex that each query your IP's. In your result code, do something and in your fault code, do something else. (Note: this method only works if you are trying to hit publicly accessable webpages that all have crossdomain.xml files in the server roots)

Comment: My problem regarding the way to obtain an IP address for my device. That is, I have no IP address before. For that, I think of sending an ARP probe message to a randomly-chosen IP to verify if it's available or not. Does your application acknowledge that it has its own IP address before ?

Comment: I have a known set of IP's. As you do not, that will add a bit more complexity, but still doable. How are you randomly choosing the IP? Typing it into the Flex UI or having Flex randomly pick one? Either way, you can pass that chosen IP to your middle layer service as a parameter and have it ping on that IP instead if a fixed IP.

Comment: The way I'm using to randomly generate IP address is Link Local address http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address. With that Ip in hand, I want to create an ARP probe message and then broadcast it. If no one claims his usage of that address, I will use it as my IP address, In contrast, I will try out another IP.